# I want to delete my accepted answer

Tags: discussion, support, accepted-answer

I have an [answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/9501/how-to-test-what-shell-i-am-using-in-a-terminal/9503#9503) that was helpful enough for the OP to accept, but I think the other answer is better (it includes mine too), so I want to delete mine. Is that OK?

To those who wonder why I asked:

[image]

Comment: Why even ask. Your answer is wrong even. Note that it can always be undeleted as well.

Comment: @Tshepang I thought I stressed the "accepted" part, but apparently that wasn't enough.

Comment: Oh, I didn't know Accepted answers can't be deleted by a normal user. In such a case, just flag it.

Answer (score 2):

You are free to delete your answers any time, and it is always acceptable (encouraged, even) to delete your answer if you feel other answers cover the same ground.

(The only time this is a problem, is when people decide to self-immolate and delete all their content ... aka [ragequit](http://knowyourmeme.com/memes/rage-quit). We have some protection in place for this now.)

Comment: But please see my update, I cannot delete the answer because it was accepted.

Comment: @phune flag it for moderator attention with an explanation